# Can I install Auto Layout constraints in views that are owned by VCs outside of my control?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am new to Auto Layout. I would like to convert an existing project to Auto Layout. The project does not use Interface Builder, the entire view hierarchy is set up programmatically.

After reading Apple's [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutConcepts/AutoLayoutConcepts.html) and doing a bit of experimenting, I am still unclear as to whether I am allowed to install constraints in views that are **NOT** owned by one of my own custom view controllers? The question is particularly interesting in the case of UIKit's predefined view controller classes, but can actually be extended to any third party view controller's that are outside of my control.

To explain my uncertainty, let's take a look at this example of a view hierarchy:

```
+-- UIWindow -----------------------------------+
| +-- UINavigationController (?) -------------+ |
| | +-- MyViewController (UIView) ----------+ | |
| | | +-- ViewOne ------------------------+ | | |
| | | |                                   | | | |
| | | +-----------------------------------+ | | |
| | | +-- ViewTwo ------------------------+ | | |
| | | |                                   | | | |
| | | +-----------------------------------+ | | |
| | +---------------------------------------+ | |
| +-------------------------------------------+ |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I am clearly responsible for the layout of the subviews `ViewOne` and `ViewTwo`. Since I want to use Auto Layout, I enable it on both of the subviews (by setting the subview's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to `NO`), then I install the appropriate constraints on `MyViewController`'s view.

Now let's go up in the view hierarchy. Again, since I want to use Auto Layout, I enable it on the subview, which this time is `MyViewController`'s view (by setting the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to `NO`). But what should I do about the constraints?

1. Blithely install the desired constraints in `UINavigationController`'s view? This strongly feels as if I am violating `UINavigationController`'s encapsulation. Since I have no idea about `UINavigationController`'s internal view hierarchy, how am I supposed to install a constraint that is not messing up the `UINavigationController` view layout? And which view should I install it in, since I don't know the internal view hierarchy?
2. Install no constraints at all in `UINavigationController`'s view? At first glance, this seems the right thing to do, because now I am not violating encapsulation - I just leave it up to `UINavigationController` how it wants to layout my view and which constraints it wants to install on its own. However, my experiments seem to clearly indicate that is not the right solution because `UINavigationController` never seems to install any constraints on its own - which can result in `MyViewController`'s view getting a zero-sized frame. A copy&paste'able code example demonstrating this behaviour is available upon request.

Can someone knowledgeable about Auto Layout please provide some conceptual guidance here? Is one of the two solutions above correct, which one, and why? Or am I somehow fundamentally confused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first instinct was right, do not create constraints for `MyViewController`'s view. `UINavigationController` is a container view controller. It takes a view controller and decides how to lay out the child controller's view. You shouldn't care whether it does that using springs and struts or auto-layout.

If it wants to use auto-layout, **it** will set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`.`MyViewController` should not be doing that part. Top-level views (the ones that directly back a view controller) should have that property set to `NO`. Open the source of an auto-layout enabled storyboard, and you'll see that top-level views don't have that set to `YES` either (whereas all other views do).

That means that if you were to create a custom container controller, that container has to set the property to `NO` and install any constraints. The custom container manages its view (which contains `MyViewController`'s view in this case), and is responsible for laying out its subviews.

Comment: Aaah, the blinding light... :-) I can't give you more than one upvote but it would be awesome if you could remember an official document where you got this information from.

Comment: See the View Controller Programming Guide, for example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html. Though it doesn't talk specifically about auto-layout, it's easy to take what's explained there and apply it to auto-layout.